# What it's the easiest way to add a flash frontpage without alter Views node page?

Tags: 6

I'm using Views to render content in frontpage, but now, I want create a single flash presentation page as frontpage that links to the current frontpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Themekey if its a different look and feel altogether... or Frontpage. Although you can create a node and have that node set as the frontpage in the sites configuration page. You have to use jQuery to have the page render the flash in drupal. As for redirection, what you will have to do is create a jQuery or actionscript that gets redirected at the end of the presentation or use the rule module that gets the page redirected after your particular condition is met. That is what I used on a previous project.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just embed the flash in a normal html page and when the animation finishes have a link at the end that links to your drupal site. I know splash pages are a bit dated now but then again so is having a flash intro.

Answer (score 0):

Create a block and enable the block on Front Page...

Comment: Sorry, it's not I looking for..
I want a single page that only shows my flash presentation as frontpage, and after flash ends the page go to current/real frontpage.

Comment: You may need to write a Javascript or Action in flash that redirects user to the link once flash is completed... If you don't have access to the flash piece then write a jQuery or Javascript timer to redirect after certain time...

Comment: Yes, I know that, but if I set flash presentation as frontpage in drupal settings, Views doesn't render content in '/nodes'

Comment: You can have only one front page in Drupal Instance that will be treated as "Home" page... You can set a cookie or session to redirect user to flash screen if cookie or session is not set when user is in Home Page.. Set cookie or session after flash presentation and redirect user to Home Page.. That should solve what you are looking for i guess...